# Java Event Driven Development problem with square bracket in assertEquals

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testing, assertion

I do classic Event Driven Development Testing.

// given

// when

```
// then
then(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK.value());

then(response.getContentAsString()).isEqualTo(
      jsonRequestProduct.write(List.of(newProduct)).getJson());
```

And I will get response from second line of code.

> org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError:  Expecting: ... but was not.

```
Expected :"[{"id":1,"description":"iPhone 33","price":599.99}]"
Actual   :"{"id":1,"description":"iPhone 33","price":599.99}"
```

**Question: How do i get rid of "[ ]" so my test will pass?**

Thanks for advice.

UPDATE:

> Required type: List<xxx.demo.model.Product>
>
> Provided: Product

This is how my controller looks like.

```
    @PutMapping("/update")
    public ResponseEntity<Product> updateProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
         return ResponseEntity.ok(productServiceImpl.updateProduct(product));
    }
```

Comment: You're creating a `List` with `List.of(newProduct)`, simply don't do that?

Comment: @Lino I have updated my post. Please Have a look at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do it that way test will pass.

```
@PutMapping("/update")
public Product updateProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
     return productServiceImpl.updateProduct(product);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `List.of` call. You assertion is telling you it expects a list/array but only got a single object.

Comment: I have updated post. Please have a look.